# curl gives 403 error while trying to run exec command on kubenetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I m trying to execute the command inside the container using Kubernetes API.  while the command work using kubectl

> kubectl exec shell-demo -- bash -c env

but same gives 403 error when using Kubernetes web API(kubectl proxy) using curl.

```
$ curl -k -v POST  http://192.168.1.44:5443/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/shell-demo/exec?command=bash&command=-c&command=env&container=nginx&stderr=true&stdout=true
    [1] 405247
    [2] 405248
    [3] 405249
    [4] 405250
    [5] 405251
    [2]   Done                    command=-c
    [3]   Done                    command=env
    [4]-  Done                    container=nginx
    [farooq@farooq-pc ansible-vbox-vagrant-kubernetes]$ * Could not resolve host: POST
    * Closing connection 0
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
    *   Trying 192.168.1.44:5443...
    * Connected to 192.168.1.44 (192.168.1.44) port 5443 (#1)
    > GET /api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/shell-demo/exec?command=bash HTTP/1.1
    > Host: 192.168.1.44:5443
    > User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
    > Accept: */*
    >
    * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
    < HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
    < Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    < Date: Thu, 18 Nov 2021 19:54:34 GMT
    < Content-Length: 10
    <

Forbidden
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same problem `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST` when you are trying `curl -k -v -X POST <host+commands>`? This could suggest that you doesn't have problem with `curl`, but with DNS. What are your DNS settings?

Comment: I m using ip directly in command.  No dns required

Comment: You have got [curl(6) error](https://bobcares.com/blog/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-ubuntu/): This error mainly occurs due to a wrong DNS set up or bad settings on the server. Are you sure that your request doesn't have typo? Please also paste the output / error message when you are using `curl` from the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your curl command looks wrong. Try it with -X in front of the POST like this: `curl -k -v -X POST http://192.168.1.44:5443/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/shell-demo/exec?command=bash&command=-c&command=env&container=nginx&stderr=true&stdout=true` 
also make sure if you need POST at all, since you don't add any data (-d mypostbody) it could be a simple GET request with urlencoded-data depending on your API endpoint aswell.

Comment: I tried the command your provided with POST and GET but get the same error. **curl -k -v -X GET http://192.168.1.44:5443/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/shell-demo/exec?command=bash&command=-c&command=env&container=nginx&stderr=true&stdout=true** Is there any example on command with URL encoded data?

Comment: url encoded data can be appended with ?key=value by hand in your url on a simple GET, make sure that you use the correct data transmission GET or POST and urlencoded data https://<url>?key=val&key2=val2 inside the url or urlencoded data like key=val&key2=val2 in a post body data... that depends on your API endpoint

Comment: also if GET is what you are looking for you can remove -X GET entirely

Comment: The solution is to use WebSockets. And curl does not support them. I don't think we can have a solution to this using curl.